Tsiolkovsky rocket equation assumptions
From what I understand, the elementary derivation of the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation makes the assumption that mass is lost as a linear function of time.
Why do we make this assumption? Does it follow from assuming the exhaust velocity is constant?

It's how rockets approximately work. There is a maximum burn rate for which the rocket engine is designed, and that burn rate is used for some time, until the fuel tank is nearly empty.

So the rocket’s burn rate is constant enough for long enough, that the change in burn rate near the end is negligible in calculating the rocket’s final velocity? I’d imagine they probably have a better idea of the actual m(t) function from experiment with the design before they launch.

The derivation of the Tsiolkovsky rocket equation does not require that the mass ejection rate is constant, only that $v_\text{ex}$ is constant.  Using conservation of momentum, it is possible to show that a "small" change of mass $d m$ of the rocket leads to a change in velocity $d v$ given by
$$
dv = - v_\text{ex} \frac{dm}{m} \tag{1}
$$
If the exhaust velocity is constant, this can be integrated on both sides to yield
$$
\Delta v = v_\text{ex} \ln \left( \frac{m_i}{m_f} \right)
$$
without any assumptions about the rate at which mass was ejected in the process.  In other words, assuming a constant exhaust velocity, $\Delta v$ depends only on the initial and final masses, and not on how you transitioned between them.
The derivation would change at the equation (1) if the exhaust velocity was not constant.  If, for example, $v_\text{ex}$ was a known function of $t$, equation (1) would become
$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = -v_\text{ex}(t) \frac{dm}{dt}
$$
and at this point we would need to know the mass ejection rate to integrate both sides with respect to $t$ and find $\Delta v$.

Thank you for your answer. In principle m(t) could be anything, but the resulting velocity equation only establishes a relationship between velocity and mass right? Time is not included. In other words, there isn’t a way to get m(t) from this sort of derivation without assuming a particular mass rate of change?

@wonderwave:  That's correct, though the way I'd state it is that the $\Delta v$ depends only on the initial and final masses and not on how you transitioned between them.  (Assuming a constant exhaust velocity.)

Ah ok. I understand now, especially with that phrasing. Thanks again.
